# Why cannot I access to all attributes of LDAP?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ldap

I'm developing one JavaScript web services with Node.js 6.11.0 and MongoDB. My web services needs perform LDAP query.

I'm using ldapjs package (version 1.0.1). Below my LDAP module JavaScript file:

```
var ldap = require("ldapjs");

function bind(username, password, callback) {
    try {
        let client = _getClient(global.config.ldap.host);
        client.bind(username, password, function (err) {
            callback(err, client);
        });
    } catch (err) {
        callback(err);
    }
}

function search(client, dn, opts, callback) {

    let arr = [];
    if (!opts) opts = {};

    client.search(dn, opts, function (err, res) {
        if (err) {
            callback(err);
            return;
        }

        res.on('searchEntry', function (entry) {
            arr.push(entry);
        });
        res.on('error', function (err) {
            callback(err);
        });
        res.on('end', function (result) {
            global.logger.log('status: ' + result.status);
            callback(undefined, arr);
        });
    });
}

function _getClient(host) {
    return ldap.createClient({
        url: host
    });
}

exports.bind = bind;
exports.search = search;
```

I'm querying with this code:

```
let appUser = "utente";
let appPass = "password";

let userDn = global.config.userDn.replace("{uid}", appUser);

ldapUtils.bind(userDn, appPass, function (err, client) {
    if (err) {
        return;
    }

    global.logger.info("Bind success...");

    var opts = {
        scope: "sub"
    };

    ldapUtils.search(client, global.config.shopsDn, opts, function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            global.logger.error(err);
            return;
        }

        global.logger.info("Search success...");
        data[3].attributes[0]._vals[0...n]; // Here I cannot view all attributes.

        res.send();
    });
});
```

I cannot view all attributes that I can view with *Apache Directory Studio* using same authentication parameters.

[image: Apache Directory Studio...]

Can you help me?

**Edit**

I specified the attributes but the problem remains:

```
 var opts = {
        scope: "sub",
        attributes: ["dn", "cn", "customAttribute"]
 };
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Although it is supposed to return all attributes if none are specified, try adding attributes to your search options, eg:

```
var opts = {
    scope: "sub"
    attributes: ["dn", "cn", "description", "objectGUID"]
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You should allow use on [paging](http://ldapjs.org/client.html#paging)

```
     var opts = {
        paged: true,
        attributes = {
           user: [
             'dn', 'distinguishedName',
             'userPrincipalName', 'sAMAccountName', /* 'objectSID', */ 'mail',
             'lockoutTime', 'whenCreated', 'pwdLastSet', 
             'userAccountControl',
             'employeeID', 'sn', 'givenName', 'initials', 'cn', 'displayName',
             'comment', 'description'
             ],
           group: [
             'dn', 'cn', 'description', 'distinguishedName', 
            'objectCategory'
           ]}
       };
```

Comment: please explain why